# Send over 2000 e-mails with PHP mail function

Tags: php, email

I am trying to create a system that sends an e-mail to everyone of the users of my webpage.

It seems though that there are too many emails - about 2400 emails, to send for it to work.

Is there a smarter way, or a way to send 10 at a time or something like that?

Here is my code:

```
<?php


include('../../includingThis.php');



$fra = "ME <me@me.com>";
$emne = "";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sendThese WHERE id=1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


$emne = $row["subject"];
$message = $row["message"];
$mailsHere = $row["mailsHere"];
$til = explode(",", $mailsHere);

    }
}
$besked = file_get_contents('sendThese.html');
$besked = str_replace("%%message%%", $message, $besked);


// HEADERS
$headers = "MIME-Version:1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UFT-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$fra."\r\n";

// Mail til ejeren af siden

$mailsSend = 0;

foreach ($til as $value) {
    mail($value,$emne,$besked,$headers);
    $mailsSend++;
    echo $value . "<br>";
    sleep(2);


}




// Sender vi brugeren videre til en side
//header("Location: index.php");
echo "Done - " . $mailsSend . " e-mails sendt.";

die();


?>
```

Comment: *"It seems though that there are too many emails - about 2400 emails, to send for it to work."* - Why do you think that?

Comment: I hope this `sleep(2);` you had for debug purpose only

Comment: Btw, since the body of the mail seems to be exactly the same for all of them, you could send it to yourself and put all these addresses in the BCC. This does affect the recipient information the receiver will see, though. And if there are differences (for example their name in the subject or other specific content), this is, obviously, not possible and you'll have to send them one by one.

Comment: I tried it, and only a few have received it. I myself have not received it. And I cannot do BCC because they would be able to see each others emails.

I used sleep(2) in order for it not to send them all at once?

Comment: You are incorrect about BCC. Nobody else will see who gets the email that's what it's called BLIND carbon copy.

Comment: @Dave didn't know that. How do I send them as BCC then?

Comment: Suggest you look into using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). I would also point out that if you are trying to send that many pieces of mail your hosting provider is likely to consider it spam and cut you off even with a delay between each mail sent.